# Customizer JS API: Adding a "dropdown-pages" control

Tags: javascript, theme-customizer, api

What is a proper way to add a list of pages (`type: dropdown-pages`) using Customizer JS API?

Currently, I have this code but it does not display a control:

```
api.control.add( new api.Control( 'custom-control', {
  type: 'dropdown-pages',
  section: 'custom-section',
  setting: new wp.customize.Setting( 'custom-control', '0' ),
  label: 'Select Page'
} ) );
```

If I change the type to, for example, `text` then the control is shown in the section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, that doesn't work… yet. We didn't add support for the `dropdown-pages` control in [#30738](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/30738) because we wanted to leverage the REST API for this control to fetch the pages. So in 4.9 this is the only base control that requires server-side rendering in core. However, in 4.9 it is easy to provide our own implementation of a content template for the `dropdown-pages` control.

I've written a [standalone example plugin](https://gist.github.com/westonruter/00c351830e0a15cef7672b748720a7ff) which includes [control template](https://gist.github.com/westonruter/00c351830e0a15cef7672b748720a7ff#file-wpse-286375-php-L64-L166) for the `dropdown-pages` control type. With that template included, you can create controls in the same way you are doing here. Follow [#42272](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42272) for upcoming core implementation.

Alternatively, you may want to consider the [Customize Object Selector](https://wordpress.org/plugins/customize-object-selector/) plugin, as it provides a control which uses Select2 to provide a searchable interface for selecting one or more pages. See [example usage](https://github.com/xwp/wp-customize-posts/blob/1a5521c0d5bed3c84aaf9dffcd3eb77950bb8c70/js/customize-post-section.js#L635-L655) in the [Customize Posts](https://github.com/xwp/wp-customize-posts) plugin.